# Why Google search displays only the English title of a bilingual website?

Tags: seo, google-search

My website is in two languages; English and Turkish. 
I used Resources.resx files to create this bilingual website, and my filenames are:

```
    Resources.resx (default which is Turkish)
    Resources.tr-TR.resx (for Turkish only)
    Resources.en-EN.resx (for English only)
```

The homepage title is supposed to be Turkish because default title is Turkish.

```
    MyWebSite.Resources.Resources.HomePageTitle;
```

So, in Google search I expect to see the Turkish title because "HomePageTitle" has Turkish title by default. But all I see is the English result of my search; my website's English title comes on screen and when I click the result, the page opens in Turkish, however.

Any tips on what I can do to get the search result in default language and not in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how your bilingual website works but I suspect it detects a users language and serves the content in that language.

This means the one URL is used for all languages and there is no way for a request to specifically indicate a language.

When Googles bot comes along it comes from the USA and defaults to English, so that is what Google will see and use.

If this is the case, you will have to re-structure how you serve the different language versions so they have different URLs. I'd also look into "rel hreflang" which is a way to tell Google which URL represents which language.